# Qt: "Expected type-specifier" appearing on one device and not another with same code

Tags: c++, qt

A friend and I are beginners with C++ and Qt. We are working on a Qt project together (the helicopter game) and when she sent me the code she had on her computer, which ran without errors, it gave the "expected type-specifier" error on a line that set a pointer equal to a new instance our "game" constructor. Is there something wrong with the code or does it have something to do with my computer?

This is where our error appears in the main function:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

//including for splash screen
#include <QSplashScreen>
#include <QTimer>

//our header files
#include "player.h"
#include "game.h"

game * heli_game;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSplashScreen * splash = new QSplashScreen;
    splash->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/splash.png"));
    splash->show();

    game * heli_game;
    heli_game = new game::game();   //ERROR HERE: "expected type-specifier"


    QTimer::singleShot(2500, splash, SLOT(close()));

    return a.exec();
}
```

And here's our game header file where the constructor is defined:

```
#ifndef GAME
#define GAME

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include "player.h"
#include "score.h"
//#include "game_over.h"

class game: public QGraphicsView{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //constructors
    game(QWidget* parent=NULL);

    //public attributes
    QGraphicsScene * scene;
    player * copter;
    score * Score;
//  game_over * game_over;

};

#endif // GAME
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I thought I had tried that before and it hadn't worked but it's running that part without error now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
new game::game();
```

^ This would only make sense if the `game` class is in a namespace called `game`.  Since it isn't, the compiler has no way of knowing what type you're referring to.

What you probably meant to do was this:

```
new game();
```

I should also point out that `heli_game` is declared twice in your main file.

Answer (score 0):

```
heli_game = new game::game();
```

is incorrect, it should be

```
heli_game = new game();
```

only. Your code shouldn't have compiled with any compiler.

By the way you have a "heli_game *game" global variable and another inside main().